# How do I print the correlationID of a sharepoint request?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to display a requests CorrelationID to the screen.  What API can I use to display this information?

For example, in a sharepoint 2010 webpart I'd like to print this sentence.

"Your current correlation ID is {TheCorrelationGuid}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this into your class:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern uint EventActivityIdControl(uint controlCode, ref Guid activityId);
```

and then use this in your code:

```
var g = new Guid();
EventActivityIdControl(1, ref g);
```

g should now contain the current correlation ID.